# Inequality of product of matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality

Is this inequality true?
$X^T P Y \ge \lambda_{min}(P)X^TY $ 
if
  $P$ is a positive definite matrix and $Y=sgn(X)$ where $X$ is a vector, $sgn(X)$ is a vector which its elements are the sign of the elements of the vector $X$, $\lambda_{min}(P)$ is the minimum eigenvalue of $P$.
Generally, can you give my an inequality that relates $X^T P Y$ to $X^T Y$?

Comment: Add fast more information about $P,X,Y,i,f$ or some forummember will you downvote^^

Comment: Hint: Do you know the defintion of an eigenvalue https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors and use $P v=\lambda v$ for $v$  is a column vector

Comment: What does $P>0$ mean?

Comment: It means it is positive definite

Comment: I think you have permitted $X$ and $Y$ you mean $Y^t  PX$ I think

Comment: This doesn't sound plausible. Have you tried any numerical experiment?

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong. Consider
$$ P = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
with least eigenvalue $\lambda\in (0,1]$ (the exact value doesn't matter) and for $\epsilon > 0$
$$ x = \begin{bmatrix} \epsilon \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad
y = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then, we have
\begin{align*} 
x^T P y - \lambda x^T y
&= x^T (P - \lambda I) y \\
&=\begin{bmatrix} \epsilon \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} 2 - \lambda & -1 \\ -1 & 1 - \lambda \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} \epsilon \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix} 1-\lambda \\ -\lambda \end{bmatrix}  \\
&= \epsilon(1-\lambda) - \lambda \to -\lambda < 0
\end{align*}
for $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: It worth mentioning that $\lambda x^\top y = x^\top (\lambda I) y$